# Python output not showing on Mac Terminal

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7

I have a very simple code that I wanted to execute;

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys

def Hello(name):
    name = name + '!!!!'
    print('Hello', name)

if __name__ == '___main___':
    Hello(sys.argv[0])
```

and on the Terminal (I'm using iterm2, Mac OSX 10.11.3).

```
python lesson1.py aaaa
```

and is not showing anything.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

`___main___` has three underscores surrounding `main`. It should be two:

```
___main___
↑        ↑
```

TO

```
__main__
```

Comment: I have shamed myself...  (ㄒoㄒ)